# Beveling a BezierCircle with anonther BezierCircle, but the outcome is oval

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel

I'm trying to make a kind of cage for a sword handle, and thougt doing that with Biziers an beveling should do the trick but I ran straight into this issue:

The outcome I want to get, should look similar to this:

[image: final result (but somewhat angular profile]

I used a normal BezierCircle as Bevel-Object:
[image: Bevel-Object]

for another BezierCircle, but I got a oval profile then:
[image: oval outcome]

I kinda solved it when I went to edit mode and resized the Bevel-Object in X direction, but then the final profile looks somewhat angular.

I would appreciate if someone here can tell me what I'm doing wrong here, or whats the problem, especially because I did the same thing with the vertical Beziers and the profile in this case was correct. And (at least I think so) I did the same steps in both cases.

**Second Question** *(not THAT important so I don't want to open an extra question for that)*:
With this solution to the cage it feel like this object alone has double the amount of quads then the rest of the sword. No Problem in this case, because I don't really plan to use it elsewhere.
But if I want to keep the model low poly, I feel like I need another approach to this. Perhaps one of you could give me a hint for a new view to the Problem.

Thx in advance ^^

Comment: The cage bezier curve is problably scaled along an axis. Concerning your second question, you can adjust the resolution of both curves (see at the top of the curve properties)

Comment: True that. Damn. I must have changed the ratio between the axes while changing the size of the Circle. Problem solved.

Concerning my second question: Totally nailed it! Did not thougt that I can ALSO change the resolution of the Bevel-Bezier.

Thx everything works perfectly now!
(I would like to upvote your answer, but it's just a comment. Would you copy it into an answer, so I can give you the approval you deserve? ^^)